# Subdomain read and delete primary domain cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to set a cookie from my main domain, read then remove the cookie from a subdomain. But I also need to possibly set that cookie again on the domain in the future, and read it later on the subdomain. Basically, a stream of one-way communication. I cannot have the main domain handle unsetting the cookie, because it could be months between users hitting the main domain and the subdomain.

I set a cookie on my domain, like so:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=testcookie;domain=example.com;max-age=31536000;";
```

I access it just fine on another subdomain, as such:

```
document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)testcookie\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

I then try to kill it from the subdomain:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=;domain=example.com;max-age=0;";
```

That does not work. Cookie is still set.

However, setting it like this clears it:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=;domain=example.com;max-age=31536000;";
```

It now returns `""` when asking for it from the subdomain.

But... if I go back to the domain and set it again, and I can see it has been set, the subdomain still returns `""`

Is there some sort of... hierarchy of cookies I'm missing? I'm unsure how this behaves or how to overcome this.

Comment: Try setting it using .example.com, the first period is critical.

Comment: @forrestmid Added leading period to both setter and unsetter, no change in behavior

Comment: Make sure you clear your cookies for the site first. If there are any cookies without the period then you still cannot overwrite. I just implemented a similar functionality on my site recently and experienced the same issue when I didn't use a period and it was difficult for me to insure another cookie wasn't getting set without the period.

Comment: @forrestmid have been using fresh incognitos, also manually removed site data for all sites involved. I can confirm that the code setting and attempting to reset the cookie are both now using the `.example.com` string like so: `document.cookie = "mycookie=;domain=.example.com;max-age=0;";` - still no cigar

Comment: May I ask what domain you are using? I had some issues in testing with ngrok.io. There's apparently a registry of public domains that people can issue subdomains to (like aws, heroku, etc.) that browsers prevent from setting/accessing/removing cookies at the root domain.

Comment: Also, make sure you're setting the domain from the root path `/` and removing it from the same path. You don't have to be at that path in the script but it has to set the cookie with the same path always.

Comment: @forrestmid the leading `.` plus the `path=/;` seems to have done it - you should probably post that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to enable this you have to place a period `.` before the root domain, like so: `.example.com` This is important because of the way the cookie standardization is setup. This format should be compatible with most modern browsers.

In addition, the path must be identical when accessing or modifying the cookie across different subdomains. The easiest way to do this is to just use the root path for the domain, `/`. For example, if you set the cookie from `sub1.example.com/page1` and try to access it from `sub2.example.com/page2`, even though you set the domain as `.example.com` you also have to set the `path=/` in order to access it and modify it from any path on other subdomains.

Ultimately:

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=testcookie;domain=.example.com;path=/;max-age=31536000";
```

will enable you to set it and

```
document.cookie = "mycookie=;domain=.example.com;path=/;max-age=0";
```

will let you delete it.

Comment: just a clarification that the leading dot is not necessary any more under the latest (2011) widely adopted [rfc6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#page-20)